# How to retrieve files from the windows phone (8.1) music library using path names?

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am letting my users select files from the music library. After which I am storing the path of the selected files locally. Now my problem is how do I get access to the files programmatically from these paths? Here are a couple of things I've tried.

Say my pathname is *D:\Xyz\abc.mp3*

**StorageFolder S=KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;**

Alternative 1:

**StorageFile MyFile=await S.GetFileAsync("abc.mp3");**  //File not found error

// I figure this doesn't work cause GetFileAsync method can only get files from the current folder

Alternative 2:

**S=await S.GetFolderAsync("Xyz");** //After which I planned to do GetFileAsync. But this also gives a folder not found error.

And Finally I've tried **S=await S.GetFolderAsync("D");**

Any help as to how I get access to the file or even an alternate way to achieve my goal would be fantastic !

P.S : StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("D:\Xyz\abc.mp3") says I don't have permission to access.

Comment: GetFileFromPathAsync doesn't guarantee to maintain access to files from a picker on Windows Phone 8.1. The access denied is the expected result. To maintain access you will have to use the Windows.Storage.AccessCache namespace. See my answer for one way to maintain access to a file.

Answer (score 10):

(Answer rebuild to be more clear)

If you had declared in `package.appxmanifest` file:

- `Music Library` capability in *Capabilities*
- `File Type Association` in *Declarations* (I'm not sure if this is needed if you only access Music Library)

then you will be able to retrieve files from `Music Library` folder like this:

```cs
StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
// below code will work unless 'fileName.mp3' is in 
// your Music folder either on phone or SD card
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("fileName.mp3");
// you can access them also with path, but in this case
// also Folders must be in Music folder
string path = @"Test\ccc.mp3";
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
```

To sum up you will be able to aceess by `KnownFolders.MusicLibrary` only to files which are either on Phone or SD card but in Music folder - their paths will be then:

> C:\Data\Users\Public\Music\test.mp3  - for Phone
>
> D:\Music\Test\test2.mp3  - for SD card

Remember that accessing by [StorageFolder.GetFileAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfileasync) works **relative** to the StorageFolder (it will also work with full path, see remark below):

> The name (or path relative to the current folder) of the file to retrieve.

In this case to get above files you will use filenames like: `test.mp3` and `Test\test2.mp3`.

You **won't** be able to get other files like `D:\xxx.mp3` - it isn't in Music Library - it is on SD card, if you want to access it you will have to do it by [KnownFolders.RemovableDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611857.aspx) - when you have added required capabilities, then you should be able to access that via fullpath. But also [please remember about the remark:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.path)

> Do not rely on this property to access a file because some files may not have file-system paths. For example if the file is backed by a URI, or was picked using the file picker, the file is not guaranteed to have a file-system path.

In our discussion tured out that you are using `CommonFileQuery.OrderByName` to get files. As I've checked there (IMO) might be a little bug - in VS description says that:

> Query results for deep queries include all files in all of the **subfolders** of the folder being queried and sorts them based on the specified metadata.

Running a pice of code:

```cs
// a method to retrieve files from Musiic Library recursively 
private async Task RetriveFilesInFolders(List<StorageFile> list, StorageFolder parent)
{
   foreach (var item in await parent.GetFilesAsync()) list.Add(item);
   foreach (var item in await parent.GetFoldersAsync()) await RetriveFilesInFolders(list, item);
}

// then I've used it like this:

StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;

List<StorageFile> listOfFiles = new List<StorageFile>();
await RetriveFilesInFolders(listOfFiles, folder);
// as a result of above code I have a List of 5 files that are in Music Library

List<IStorageItem> filesFolders = (await folder.GetItemsAsync()).ToList();
List<StorageFile> items = (await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName)).ToList();
// as a result here I've 14 files that are in Music Library and SD card, and Phone
```

has given resuls:

- in first case 5 files that are in fact in Music folder and its subfolders,
- in second case - 14 files that are in: Music Library, SD card, and Phone

You can easily look at the `Path` in debug mode and you will see that some of files in second method has `D:\file.mp3` and so on - they aren't in Music Library - so you won't be able to get them by `KnownFolders.MusicLibrary`. If you want to get them then you will have to use other KnownFolders - in this case SD card:

```cs
StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
StorageFolder sdCard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
StorageFile file = await sdCard.GetFileAsync("xyz.mp3"); // for D:\xyz.mp3
StorageFile file = await sdCard.GetFileAsync("XYZ\xyz.mp3"); // for D:\XYZ\xyz.mp3
```

Comment: I've Music Library Capability ticked. I'm fetching all the files from library and letting users select them. Then I am storing the file paths, till which its fine. Now I want to access those files later in my app. 

And like I said StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("fileName.mp3"); does NOT work. And I am confident that such a file exist in the library cause I've fetched the name from the StorageFile objects my user selected. An easy way would be to do GetFilesAsync(Query) each time and search for my file in the result. But that would lead to awful performance.

Comment: @Aditya I think you shouldn't use `Path`, but `Name` and parent Folder. Look that `StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary` gives you access to Music Library - you should GetFiles relative to it. I'm not sure if remembering Path or Name is a good way - look that Music Lib can be on SD Card and in Phones memory, user can switch files between them. You should also check if user hadn't deleted file.

Comment: Have tried using name as well, doesn't work. And none of the delete, move situation is happening cause am doing it in my phone/emulator.

Comment: @Aditya I've tried this on a device and it should work. I haven't understood - are you testing it on emulator or device?

Comment: Did both. Same error. And can you elaborate what worked in your case?

Comment: @Aditya I've edited answer, and added the code I've checked - it is working. Have you added File Type Association in declarations? And are you using Win8.1 RT or Silverlight?

Comment: Can you tell me how your path for item[1] look like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51450/discussion-between-romasz-and-aditya)

Comment: In my case, I had to add "Removable Storage" capability as well (in addition to Music Library). After that, it start working.

Comment: @Illidan If you want to access files on SD Cards - the yes, you have to add that capability. It depends on the path of the file you want to access.

Comment: @ Romasz All I wanted is to access KnownFolders.MusicLibrary folder. Until I declared "Removable Storage", I got access denied. After I declared - it started to work

Comment: @Illidan There might be such a possiblity as Music Library is a virtual location and in fact exists on both Phone and SD card. I haven't check if accessing single file in Music on SD via MusicLibrary requires Removable capability. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: @Romasz : I wanted to know how are you updating the list when the user changes content in his MusicLibrary. Do you check every time the app opens by making the data persistent cause that takes a lot of time or do you try doing it in the background?

Comment: @AbsoluteSith For now I don't have such a need. There is no available event that would help you. I think the best would be to provide the user a button like 'synchronize' or do it somehow in background with some indicator running, informing the user that something is going on.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have the proper capabilities set. The error you're getting is what you'd see if you didn't declare the right CAP_ID . Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Regarding file paths, depending where the file is stored, you may need to use the double-slash. I had a similar issue, I resolved by using the following approach:

> "isostore:shared\\folderName\\NameOfFile.mp3"

You can see the whole process in [my SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387735/how-to-get-image-path-saved-to-wp8-local-folder-for-live-tile).

Comment: Its a wp 8.1 app and I've Music Library Capability ticked. I'm fetching all the files from library and letting users select them. Then I am storing the file paths, till which its fine. Now I want to access those files later in my app. And yes double slashed, still same.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the [access cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemaccesslist.aspx) to store access to the files instead of the paths. This will let you retrieve StorageFile objects that you can work with right away, and will help with some scenarios surrounding files being moved.

To store a file in the access cache

```
 StorageFile file; //Get a file
 string mruToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Add(file, "20120716");
```

You then save the token some where. To get the file back from the cache:

```
 StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.getFileAsync(mruToken);
```

Storing just the path opens you up to issues with drive letters changing ect. This ensures that if the file is still available, your app can get it.