# WIndows Phone 8.1 check for new media files

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, checksum, contentobserver

Whats is the best way to check if there are any new media files that are available in the Gallery on windows phone 8.1 ?

I see that there is no content observer API in WP81 like iOS7 or Android.

I currently am calculating checksums for each file with its name and size and storing locally using the windows.storage list and each time when its time to check for new items, i create the checksum again for every file and compare that to the saved checksum list.

This brings a huge overhead when the number of files are more.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this ?

Comment: Probably there is no easy solution. [Similar question is here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23724001/2681948).

Answer (score 0):

there is no current API to do this, So in this case, I'm afraid you will have to list your files in Media Files (MusicLibrary for example ) and then decide, what to save for future comparison. The sum of filesizes can be a good idea, hence there is a little chance that two different music files would be the same size. It depends also if you want to be notified if the user had moved file from one folder to another (total size won't change). If you want to ensure more you can remember the whole list of        `Tuple<file.FolderRelativeId, fileSize>`
As FileQueries are not yet available for Windows Phone, you will have to retrive files recursively the simple code can look like this:

```
 // first - a method to retrieve files from folder recursively 
private async Task RetriveFilesInFolder(List<StorageFile> list, StorageFolder parent)
{
foreach (var item in await parent.GetFilesAsync()) list.Add(item);
foreach (var item in await parent.GetFoldersAsync()) await RetriveFilesInFolder(list, item);
}

private async Task<List<StorageFile>> GetFilesInMusic()
{
StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
List<StorageFile> listOfFiles = new List<StorageFile>();
await RetriveFilesInFolder(listOfFiles, folder);
return listOfFiles;
}
```

Once you have a list of your files, you can decide what to remember for further comparison upon next app launch.