# How to access phone memory & search files with certain extensions in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing Windows Phone 8.1. I can use `KnownFolders.RemovableDevices` to access SD card & further can retrieve files & folders. Some WP devices don't have SD cards, then how can I access phone memory to retrieve files?

Windows 8 has [`CreateFileQueryWithOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211591.aspx) and on MSDN [Windows.Storage.Search namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.aspx) says that it supports WP8.1 but it's throwing `NotImplementedException`. So how can I search files in WP8.1 devices?

Comment: you tagged both silverlight and windows-runtime (RT).  They have two different API's.  You should specify which one you are using, or specify that you are, in fact, using both of them.

Comment: File queries are not supported on WP81 Silverlight apps. So, the only way to do so is to arrange files by correct folder (let say, log files to "logs" subfolder, temp files into their temp folder etc). Otherwise, you'll end up with full manual scan like folder.GetFilesAsync().Where(foo).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone, you can have access only to [KnownFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx) (apart from IsolatedStorage and so on) and only after specifing the Capabilities and FileExtensions. So if you want to retrive Music files, you will use `KnownFolders.MusicLibrary`.

Note that KnownFolders (apart from RemovableStorage) are [virtual location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dd758096) - it can exist both on Phone and SD card.

If you want to search for files, there is an option to use `CommonFileQuery.OrderByName`, but I've encountered [some problems posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23296085/2681948).