# List mp3 files on windows phone with c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have the following code where i'm trying to list an image and mp3 files from the emulator local folder. Only the image is being displayed but the songs are not displayed.

```
 private void ListSongs()
        {

            MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary();

            var SongName = (from m in lib.Songs

                            select m.Name).ToList();

            Sg.Add(new ListSongs() { listImg = "images/ico.png", songList = SongName.ToString() });
            listIt.DataContext = Sg;

            //list1.ItemsSource = SongName;


        }
```

Please help me solve this issue . I'm a new member to stackoverflow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294495/how-to-retrieve-files-from-the-windows-phone-8-1-music-library-using-path-name